# How Eloquent ORM creates its data structure on eager loading

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have been looking into eloquent's source code to see how it manages building its data structure when eager loaded with one or more relationships specified but I have not been successful.

For instance:

```
User has many photos, and a photo belongs to a User
```

1. How does eloquent perform its SQL query?
2. Does it make multiple SQL? A query to get the user and then another one to get his/her photo, or does it perform a single query.

I am also interested to see the structure of the SQL, because I have tried lots of options and there is absolutely no way I could tell what tables each field belonged to because the returned result is just plain array of objects.

Comment: in reality, laravel would create two queries. one for fetching user, then it fetch all photos with `in (user-ids)` query. then mapping is done on application side. [source `with`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L680), if you trace its call down further, you'll end up [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1126). also try to activate `DbQueryLogs`, then look on how many queries it fired.

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks a  lot, I think your comment could be an answer instead

Comment: nah, barely, it need pretty long explanation to explain laravel's magic anyway. hope someone elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel will create at least two queries when you'll try to use eager loading.

For example, this code:

```
$users = User::with('photos')->get();
```

Will produce two queries similar to these:

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null
select * from `photos` where `photos`.`user_id` in ('1', '2', ... '99')
```

I'd recommend you to use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), if you want to better understand how raw SQL queries look like.

Sometimes using `toSql()` in `php artisan tinker` tool is also helpful:

```
\App\User::where('id', 2)->toSql()
```

Comment: `>>> App\User::where('id', 2)->with('photos')->toSql()

=> "select * from users where id = ?"`

Comment: It does not return the full sql

Comment: Yes, but it's helpful in a lot of situations. If you want to get actual SQL queries, use debugbar.